# How You Take Only The Last 10 Lines of a Text File in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to only take the last 10 lines of a text file in Haskell (tail) and output them?

I'm trying to define a function:

```
getLastTenLines :: String -> String
getLastTenLines s = unlines (take 10 (lines s))
```

However this takes the first 10 lines of a file. Can this be modified to take the last 10 lines instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I take the last n elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252851/how-do-i-take-the-last-n-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try this:

```
getLastLines :: Int -> String -> String
getLastLines n s = concat (reverse (take n (reverse (lines s))))

text = "Hello how are you? \n I'm fine how are you? \n Also good!"

tester = getLastLines 2 text
-- tester output: "I'm fine how are you? Also good!"
```

You give the function a n, the number of last lines you want, and a single string in which the text is and it returns the last n lines of the text as you wanted.